# Mapping Id attribute by Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map the `Id` attribute from my entity classes with reflection using `FluentNHibernate`.

My entities:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Entity : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Ok, my mapping class is like above:

```
public class BaseMapping<E> : ClassMap<E>
{
    public BaseMapping(string schema, string table)
    {
        Schema(schema);
        Table(table);
        Id(model => typeof(E).GetProperty("Id", typeof(int)), "Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity()
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class EntityMapping : BaseMapping<Entity>
{
    public EntityMapping() : base("dbo", "Entities")
    {
        Map(model => model.Name, "Name")
            .Length(50)
            .Insert().Update()
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

I am receiving this exception:

> {"Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)"}

When I map the Id attribute on the `EntityMapping` class...

```
Id(model => model.Id, "Id")
    .GeneratedBy.Identity()
    .Not.Nullable();
```

It's works like a charm. But the first attempt is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your properties should be marked as `virtual` for your entities. This is so the NHibernate framework can perform its magic lazy loading voodoo.

That being said. Lets assume all your entities derive from `BaseEntity` as it appears. Because of this assumption you can let the `typeparam E` understand that it will always be a `BaseEntity`.

Once you do this you can then rewrite the `BaseMapping<E>` method as such.

```
public class BaseMapping<E> : ClassMap<E>
    where E: BaseEntity
{
    public BaseMapping(string schema, string table)
    {
        Schema(schema);
        Table(table);
        Id(model => model.Id, "Id");
    }
}
```

By specifing `where E: BaseEntity` will expose the properties of `E` to your method. I have only tested this code up to the point of the mapping methods completing for multiple entity types.

As for why you recieved your message the statement

`typeof(E).GetProperty("Id", typeof(int))`

returns a type of `PropertyInfo` where you need to pass the member expression for the `memberExpression` parameter. By digging through the source of FluentNHibernate they use the Expression to evaluate to a `Member` through reflection.